# Why does SQLServer 2008 R2 take hours and hours to uninstall?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Yes, hours. As in 5, maybe 6 hours. I am sitting here staring at the uninstall progress bar stuck on 80%.

Comment: Because Microsoft hates you.

Comment: I wish you had offered that as an answer, not a comment, I would have then marked it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you disabled your anti-virus?

Comment: I don't have any AV software running. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

It *could* have just hanged... Have you tried watched system load? Process explorer is a good one to start with.

Comment: It completes. Actually there are many components to it that I must uninstall one by one, and each one takes upwards of 5 hours, and eventually completes.

Comment: In that case, try to look for bottlenecks: CPU usage, disk usage, open connections, etc. Use Process Monitor (also from technet) to look for system calls that take unusually long time.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds strange although I have seen uninstalls for SQL Server 2008 R2 take upwards to 30-40 minutes but never that long. 
Did you install every component? 
Was the SQL service running?
Were there open connections to SQL/ODBC?
Were there large dbs?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a checklist that usually makes the process go smoothly

- backup/detach your DBs
- stop all SQL services, AV, hardware/software monitoring software
- make sure you have the correct permissions (safe assumption)

Answer (score 0):

If there were processes connected to the database engine it is probably waiting on them to disconnect before it is able to detach the databases before uninstall.  Just a guess though.  It probably says in the logs somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed SQL Server 2012 about 8 or 9 times over the last few years (always on virtual platforms but lots of different ones) and have always experienced slow installation performance.

The best solution is to temporarily throw lots and lots of virtual processors/cores just to complete the installation, then revert to normal virtual hardware config afterwards.

The installer can often sit there thinking for ages about copying a file or expanding it for no good reason. CPU and memory utilization are low. Disk activity is nil during these times. The majority of 'heavy' MS installers display a similar behavior on virtual platforms. Just an MSism